# Update task - change tags

Tags: asana, asana-api

Trying to update tags associated to a task:

Request:

```
PUT https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/286045228787956
```

Request payload:

```
{"data":{"tags":[157484377992312,157484408318898,285998759647376]}}
```

Response: 400
Body:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"tags: Cannot write this property","help":"For more information on API status codes and how to handle them, read the docs on errors: https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/errors"}]}
```

Can we not edit task tags? Or am I passing wrong parameters?

Documentation does not help: https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to edit tags on a task, you need to use the endpoints

```
POST /tasks/<id>/addTag
POST /tasks/<id>/removeTag
```

as described [in a different section of the documentation you referenced](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#tags).

The payload needs to be

```
{"data":{"tag":<your_tag_id>}}
```